# Buscar saldo de estoque em determinado dia (ou dia mais próximo)

Tags: mysql, query

Tenho a tabela "saldo_dia" onde registro o produto (ID), a data e o saldo. Preciso gerar um relatório (Kardex) e buscar o saldo de determinado dia como "saldo inicial".

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: caso o usuário busque a partir de uma data que o produto não teve movimentação (ou seja, não tem "saldo_dia" para aquela data), estou buscando pelo próximo dia com saldo. Porém, pode ser que não exista esse "próximo dia", neste caso - e penso que é o mais correto - seria buscar pelo último dia com saldo. Mas como fazer isso sem gerar consultas adicionais desnecessárias?

Exemplo:

O período do relatório é de 01/12/2019 a 10/12/2019. 
O último "saldo_dia" foi dia 25/11/2019 e o próximo "saldo_dia" foi só 05/12/2019.

Qual "saldo_dia" devo exibir como saldo inicial? E como buscar corretamente por este saldo?

**EDIT**

A consulta que realizo atualmente é a seguinte:

```
SELECT SaldoDia.saldo FROM saldo_dias AS SaldoDia WHERE SaldoDia.produto_id = 1 AND SaldoDia.dia >= '2019-12-01' LIMIT 1
```

A data informada é a data inicial do relatório solicitado.

Comment: Faz o seguinte, crie um IF no teu código, se ele não encontrar nada na data atual, limite um número de dias pra que ele encontre resultados, exemplo, 7 dias e monte uma query nova dentro do if, um pra 7 dias a mais e outro pra 7 dias a menos, pode deixar este número para escolha do cliente na hora de gerar o relatório... `select * FROM tabela WHERE saldo_dia BETWEEN concat(CURRENT_DATE(), ' 00:00:00') AND concat(CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY, ' 23:59:59')`, isso te ajuda?

Comment: @JaksonFischer essa é basicamente a consulta que já faço hoje. O que estou tentando evitar é justamente ficar criando IF's. Além disso tem a questão de determinado produto pode não ter tido movimento (e portanto sem "saldo_dia") num período de 7 dias, por exemplo.

Comment: E porque não informar que não tem resultados para esse intervalo?

Comment: @JorgeB. é que pode ter movimentação no intervalo informado. O que pode não ter é um "saldo_dia" coincidindo com o dia inicial do relatório. Por exemplo, como citei acima: o relatório inicia no dia 01/12/2019, mas o último "saldo_dia" é apenas do dia 25/11/2019. Ou seja, tem movimentação, mas não tem o "saldo_dia" a partir do início do relatório. Neste caso, tenho que pegar o saldo mais próximo do início do relatório.

Comment: Mas o saldo inicial não é sempre o saldo do dia imediatamente anterior ao período solicitado no qual ocorreu uma movimentação? Neste caso não basta pegar o saldo da maior data <= data inicial do período ou, caso não exista tal movimentação, considerar o saldo zero?

Comment: @anonimo faz sentido. Não tinha pensado dessa maneira e acho que estava complicando um pouco as coisas aqui. Vou testar isso e creio que dará certo.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se não seria isso que você pretende. Dentro da data do relatório, buscar o saldo mais recente. Não enconrando um valor no período, buscar o mais recente. Caso não encontre, devolver 0.

Neste caso, a data de início do relatório é irrelevante e interessa somente a data de término, para buscar sempre valores anteriores à essa data.

```
SELECT IFNULL(
  (SELECT COALESCE(SaldoDia.saldo, 0)
    FROM saldo_dias AS SaldoDia
    WHERE
            SaldoDia.produto_id = 1
        AND SaldoDia.dia <= '2019-11-10'
    ORDER BY SaldoDia.dia DESC
    LIMIT 1),
  0
);
```

Fiddle de exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47d535/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta isso e veja se retorna o que você precisa:

```
   SELECT saldo_id, dia, saldo,

   ISNULL((SELECT SUM(saldo) FROM saldos_dias AS SaldoDiaAtual WHERE 
    SaldoDiaAnterior.saldo_id = SaldoDiaAtual.saldo_id AND SaldoDiaAnterior.dia >= 
   SaldoDiaAtual.dia),0) as total

   FROM saldos_dias AS SaldoDiaAnterior
   where SaldoDiaAnterior.id_produto=1 and SaldoDiaAnterior.dia and '2019-11-10' 
   between SaldoDiaAnterior.dia and SaldoDiaAtual.dia LIMIT 1;
```